# two array foreach echo

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am having trouble with showing my data. i have 2 arrays, i want to check it if array 2 is equal to array 1. in the sample array below the output should be like this. Any answers would be appreciated. i am a newbie

> 100000, 010000, 010000, 000001, 000001, 100000, 100000

array 1 data

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#370 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#369 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#368 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#367 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#366 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#365 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

array 2 data

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#354 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#355 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#353 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#352 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#378 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#377 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#376 (1) {
    ["stage_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

This is what i have tried and doesnt work. it only shows 100000

```
foreach ($this->stage as $index => $object)
{
    if (isset($this->items[$index]) && $object->id == $this->items[$index]->stage_id)
    {
        echo 1;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that in your foreach loop you are iterating over `$this->stage` but then in your if statement you are checking whether the current index matches an entry in `$this->items`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Are you comparing the right attributes?  Perhaps: `isset($this->items[$index]) && $object->stage_id == $this->items[$index]->id`, though I'd expect a string of 1s for output.